# how to write integration tests using pytest and how to repeat the integration tests

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest

I am new to this so please do not mind if the question is not specific enough.

I want to know how to club unit tests into a single integration test in pytest.
Furthermore, I would like to repeat the integration test in a single test session a couple of times. Please let me know if there is a way to do this in pytest.

Scenario:
I have two unit tests name `test_start_call` and `test_end_call` that are invoked by pytest in that order.

Now I wanted to repeat the process a couple of times so I did this:

```
for i in range(0,c):
      pytest.main(some command)
```

which works fine which will start the test session and tear down the test session as many times as I want with one call being made in each test session.

But I want to make several calls in a single test session and by far I have not found any way to do this since last two days. I tried looking into xdist but I don't want to start new processes in parallel. The integration tests should serially execute unit tests (start call and end call) as many times as I want in a single test session.

I am stuck. So any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Did you look into yield_fixture (http://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html#yieldfixture) and test parametrization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

review https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Then add mult marker to each test and consume it in hook *pytest_generate_tests* to provide multiple tests fixture value will be visible in --collect-only --mult 3. Using marker this way will constrain the multiple tests mechanism to only marked tests.

```
# conftest
def pytest_addoptions(parser):
    parser.addoption('--mult', default=0, help="run many tests")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    count = int(metafunc.config.getoption('--mult'))
    if count and metafunc.get_closest_marker('mult'):
        if 'mult' not in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.fixturenames.append('mult') 
        metafunc.parametrize("mult", range(count))

# testfoo
@pytest.mark.mult
def test_start_call():
    ...
```

Comment: updated to remove unused fixture in test and prefer mark to be selective on which tests should be run multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

From what you're saying, I'm not quite sure that you are using the right toolset.
It sounds like you are either trying to load test something ( run it multiple times and see if it falls over ), or trying to do something more "data driven" - aka given input values x through y, see how it behaves.

If you are trying to do something like load testing, I'd suggest looking into something like [locust](http://locust.io/).

[Here](http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=660) is a reasonable blog with different examples on driving unit tests via different data.

Again, not sure if either of these are actually what you're looking for.